# Is it possible to make a ROM converter?

Tags: emulation, nes, compilers, turbografx-16

Based on my understanding, an emulator is necessary because the machine with the emulator on it (say Windows), doesn't execute the same machine code as the target platform (6502, for example). So what an emulator does is it interprets the code line by line and executes it itself, similar to how an interpreter works.

With this in mind, would it be possible to create the equivalent of a compiler, that would convert (for example) a .PCE file into a .exe file, so that it could run on Windows without an emulator?

Comment: You can write a program that could convert a ROM to an EXE, but it would just be bundling the emulator with the ROM in the same EXE file.

Comment: You would still need to include the emulator code somehow as you need to emulate the hardware of the target platform. So yes, I'm sure it would be possible to have a single .exe, but it would just be a combination of the emulator and the ROM data

Comment: If you were working at only the CPU level, you could write a 'compiler' to convert 6502 instructions into the equivalent x86 instructions.  This could work but gets flakier as complexity increases.  You might be able to write a loop in 6502 that counts to 100 and exits, and 'compile' those instructions into x86 code that also counts to 100 and exits.  But the moment you tried to 'print the results' you would become platform dependent, and now you need an I/O system, and now your 'compiler' doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Some N64 games, like Zelda, read code off the cartridge depending on which part of the game world is loaded. The converter would have to figure out which parts of the cartridge are going to be loaded as code - and somehow tell the difference between code that is loaded, and graphics that are loaded the exact same way.

Comment: @Geo... This question is asking about video game emulators, which usually have well understood (or at least well enough understood) I/O systems. The conversion process would include translating I/O code. Otherwise your reasoning would also imply that emulation is impossible, and as you can see, it is possible.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

<sup>Note: This answer mainly focuses on the NES, since that's what I'm most familiar with.</sup>

Yes; this is called static recompilation or [static binary translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation), and it is theoretically possible -- [jamulator by Andrew Kelly does it](https://andrewkelley.me/post/jamulator.html).  However, recompilation can be incredibly difficult (to the point that falling back to interpretation at runtime may be required in some cases).  Additionally, the system's non-CPU hardware (such as graphics and sound hardware) still must be emulated.

---

Statically recompiling machine code is incredibly difficult; determining the behavior of a program by analyzing its code ahead-of-time is in some cases [provably impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  Some of the problems faced when statically recompiling a retro video game ROM include:

#### How do we determine what parts of the ROM are executable code and what parts are data?

The "obvious" way to recompile a NES ROM is to take a single pass, reading a stream of 6502 instructions and outputting a stream of x86 instructions.  However, the ROM also includes data bytes, which will produce garbage if interpreted as instructions.  These garbage instructions should never be executed, since the program would never jump to that address, but the presence of non-instruction data poses two problems:

1) The program must be able to read its own ROM.  This isn't really a hard problem at all; we just need to include an uncompiled copy of the ROM in the compiled program binary to read data bytes from.

2) We can't write a simple single-pass recompiler.  Instructions can be multiple bytes wide, so if we try to recompile a block of non-executable data, we might end up misaligned when recompiling subsequent instructions.  (As a simple (somewhat contrived) example, in 6502 machine code, the sequence of bytes `69 09 0A` is `ADC #09; ASL`, while the sequence of bytes `A5 69 09 0A` is `LDA $69; ORA #0A`.  The point at which we start executing drastically affects our results.)

So this means we have to perform much more complex code analysis in order to determine the [basic blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) of the program and compile them individually.  [jamulator](https://andrewkelley.me/post/jamulator.html) does this by starting at the interrupt vectors and following all possible branches from there.  However, this approach *still* has problems with:

#### Dynamic jumps

This is where the address to execute is computed at runtime.  In some cases, the runtime-computed address can be looked up and the corresponding x86 code can be found.  However, if the *only* way to access a basic block is via an indirect jump, the recompiler would likely have assumed that block was not executable code and thus not compiled it.

jamulator mitigates this problem using a hack: [hard-coded support in the recompiler to recognize jump table implementations in specific games](https://andrewkelley.me/post/jamulator.html#detect-jump-table).  This works, but is clearly not a general-purpose solution.

#### Bank switching

Although jamulator only supports NROM games, many NES games with more complicated mappers could switch regions of code and data in and out of the accessible address space.  This means that each jump could go to dozens of different locations in the ROM, depending on which bank is mapped to that address at runtime.

#### Dynamically generated code/self-modifying code

Although this was uncommon for NES games due to the small amount of RAM, if I remember correctly C64 software would occasionally generate and execute code at runtime, or modify code mid-execution.  This would be nearly impossible to statically predict.

#### Other hardware such as graphics and audio

The NES Picture Processing Unit and Audio Processing Unit still must be emulated.  jamulator includes an emulator for the non-CPU hardware in a runtime library, and the generated x86 code calls a library function to handle writes to memory addresses mapped to I/O operations.

Many NES games relied on precise timing between the CPU and PPU, so the generated CPU code must count the number of 6502 clock cycles taken by the executed code.  [jamulator implements this relatively simply](https://andrewkelley.me/post/jamulator.html#parallel-systems): after each NES instruction, it calls out to a runtime library which runs the rest of the hardware for a specific number of cycles.  This approach is simple to implement, but has a few disadvantages:

- CPU writes don't quite happen on the *exactly* correct cycle relative to the rest of the hardware.  The timing is only accurate to the nearest instruction, not the nearest cycle.
- Emulating the PPU and APU after every CPU instruction greatly impairs performance, since the recompiler loses opportunities to remove, combine, or reorder instructions for better performance.  Frequent switching between operations also harms the x86 CPU's cache performance and branch prediction accuracy.

A more efficient (but much more complex) approach is to predict the times at which accurate synchronization between the CPU and the rest of the hardware is needed, and use these predictions to switch between fast and cycle-accurate emulation modes as needed.

---

Although static recompilation is often possible, it can be extremely difficult.  [jamulator sometimes falls back to interpretation](https://andrewkelley.me/post/jamulator.html#dirty-assembly-tricks) when the game does something not properly handled by the static recompiler.

The accuracy of static recompilation could be improved by running the game inside of something like FCEUX's code-data logger, which emulates the game while recording the code paths it takes.  Data from an actual run of the game can be used to greatly improve the accuracy of static recompilation.  However, the "test run" recorded by the code-data logger must comprehensively exercise the possible code paths taken by the game in order to be useful.

Emulators of newer systems, such as the [Dolphin Emulator](https://dolphin-emu.org) (which emulates the GameCube and Wii) frequently use [just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), where the emulator recompiles sections of the game's code *at runtime*.  This generally provides the best of both worlds: we get the performance improvements of recompiled code, and the improved insight of being able to analyze the game's code at runtime.

Comment: This is how answers should be written. 10/10

Comment: Well, to avoide a delicate first impression, it may be a good idea to preface this with a clear statement, that **the machine emulation is still needed**, which is usually the largest part of an emulator - and using recompiled code will raise the challenge, thus **ending in an even more complicated process of emulation**. Otherwise, nice source of information.

Comment: @Raffzahn Thank you for the advice; I've re-worded the first couple of paragraphs to emphasize that point.

Comment: As a variant of your *Dynamically generated code/self-modifying code*, don't forget the concept of *using code as data*. Probably never done these days, but I recall reading somewhere (sorry, can't remember where) that it was pretty common in the old days.

Comment: The most famous example that I know of is [The Story of Mel](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html), where Mel used instructions as data.

Comment: [Yar's Revenge](https://books.google.com/books?id=DqePfdz_x6gC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93#v=onepage&q&f=false) used code as (random) data.

Comment: I've used self-modifying *data*.  For instance I would have binary data tables (In this level, do the monsters shoot, or not?) which I would access by ASR or `ASL TableLoc,X`. This popped bit 7 into carry and bit 6 into sign, and then branch on sign. Very compact and efficient codewise.  But it would corrupt the table unless it was in ROM. You bet that was intended, as backup copy protection.   Emulate that!

Comment: I imagine it would be possible for static analysis to allow for translation of tight loops, which are more likely to be performance bottlenecks and less likely to cause problems when translated.

Comment: @αCVn I recall watching a talk about a Z80-based computer that used the refresh signal as a video memory address counter. This meant that all the instructions executed during pixel rendering had to be one cycle long. As an optimization, the ROM author made the CPU jump into the BASIC string table.

Comment: I don't think this is a brilliantly written answer. It could be much, much shorter and more transparent. However, it is still good and allowed me to start thinking about writing such recompiler. Hmm..:)

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that the emulator is emulating a LOT more than just the CPU. So in addition to transpiling the 6502 code to Intel code (and don't think that's simple - making the timing come out right would be a fascinating problem), you also need to provide code (analogous to the standard libraries that any program uses) that provide an emulated I/O environment that the 6502 code can manipulate.

It'd be much easier to just bundle the emulator and program into one binary and ship that. This is what Ian Bogost did with [A Slow Year](http://bogost.com/games/aslowyear/) - the 6502 binary is just wrapped up into a binary with the emulator.

Comment: The question is also based upon a fundamental misunderstanding that the code in question exists in "lines" that can be compiled.

Comment: Okay, In what way?

Comment: @JdeBP That's not really a big deal. Replace the word line with instruction, and it is essentially correct. And considering that the programs in those days were often written in assembly where there was more or less an 1-1 mapping between lines and instructions. The misunderstanding is really minor and doesn't invalidate the question or the answers.

Comment: The most significant advantage of translating the code would be that it would run faster. If you don't need the code to run any faster, there isn't much point in translating it. And if the original code was relying on the exact timing of CPU instructions in order to achieve correct behavior, then clearly you don't need it to run faster.

Comment: @kasperd Separating machine code into instructions using static analysis can actually be quite difficult because a ROM contains intermixed instructions and data.  See the section of my answer "How do we determine what parts of the ROM are executable code and what parts are data?" for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @kasperd "*if the original code was relying on the exact timing of CPU instructions in order to achieve correct behavior, then clearly you don't need it to run faster*."  This is not correct -- if the emulator is able to run faster, it uses less CPU time.  This means the emulator will use less power, run on lower-end computers, and work better for users who want to play a game while waiting for a CPU-intensive task in the background to finish.  Additionally, a fast emulator could run a game in fast-forward to e.g. skip cutscenes or run automated tests on the game.

Comment: @NobodyNada The distinction between data and code would be trivial on an architecture where data and code are separate address spaces. But since this is ROM you can just pretend they are separate address spaces which happen to contain the same byte values. Or stated differently you keep a verbatim copy of the ROM for when you need to access it as data and a translated version for when you need to access it as code. Moreover for the code version you may need to assume that every address is a possible entry point.

Comment: @NobodyNada Assuming that every address in ROM is a possible entry point may require a few extra jump instructions in the translated code and a jump table with a pointer for every ROM address. But all of this breaks down if you need to execute code that isn't static. For example if bank switching is used or the code jumps into RAM, you cannot simply translate all of the code.

Comment: @NobodyNada I see your point about the advantage of reduced resource usage even if the code was already running fast enough. Accurate timing of translated code may still be somewhat feasible. Many instructions will take a fixed number of cycles and for any sequence of such instructions you can deduce at translation time how many cycles it would have taken and increment a variable only once for the entire sequence of such instructions. Then you only need more complicated code when: jumping, executing instructions with variable timing, communicating with timing sensitive emulated hardware.

Comment: @kasperd Treating every address as an entry point is a reasonable idea that would likely work well, although it would massively increase the size of the compiled code.  Regarding accurate timing of translated code: your suggestion is a very useful technique which resembles the [catch-up technique](http://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/Catch-up) used even by non-recompiling emulators.

Comment: @NobodyNada I am guessing about a factor 3 more than a naive translation. First do a translation covering every address reachable by a linear run through the code. Assuming instructions are 2 bytes on average this give you half of the entry points you need ready to be put into the jump table. Then run through the remaining addresses and for each of them generate code for linear execution from that starting point until you reach an address from your initial linear translation. Most of those will probably need to emulate only one instruction before reaching an address already covered.

Comment: @kasperd That would work, but dividing the instructions into basic blocks would likely allow LLVM/whatever backend to optimize the code much more effectively.

Comment: Interrupt scheduling becomes a trickier problem when using basic blocks, especially for tight while(*SomeHardwareRegister & mask); style loops which exit on a hardware register condition.

Comment: @kasperd The misunderstanding is much less minor when dealing with an era where space limitations often resulted in hacks such as reusing opcodes as data.

Comment: @chrylis As explained in my comment above that's trivial to deal with. Just treat as one ROM containing only code and one containing only data, but where both ROMs happen to contain exactly the same sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not it's possible isn't the only defining factor that goes into development. Keep in mind that the quality of an emulator is very much connected to it's ability to create TAS, Savestate, use RAMWatch, and so on, all of which would not be possible if the ROM was converted to a .EXE file. With this in mind, developers haven't been interested in creating such a thing, which is the very reason why it isn't "possible" with the knowledge that the community is likely to have.

Comment: Some of these features aren’t that difficult in a statically game.  TAS support would just require simple modifications to the runtime library handling user input, and savestates require the ability to dump the 6502’s registers and memory to disk, which can be done without too much effort.  Debugging features are a bit more complicated; breakpoints could be implemented by putting checks around jumps and falling back to interpretation when near a breakpoint, but watchpoints may be quite a bit harder.  Using built-in hardware debugging support may also be an option.

Comment: Presumably a converter would not care about these features, any more than existing PC games care about these features.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling the instructions of an arbitrary processor (e.g. a 6502) into code that will run on a modern PC should be pretty easy.  After all, it's not far different from what's done by any just-in-time compiler for a language that's distributed as bytecode (e.g. Java, .NET, and so on) and simpler than a JIT compiler for a language that needs non-trivial parsing (e.g. Javascript).  The easy way would be to use an existing code generator (e.g. LLVM or gcc) and just add a very simple front end that read the machine code and generated the appropriate intermediate instructions...

There are three things that make this much more complex than it seems:

- First, you'd need to emulate the hardware other than the CPU, so the graphics system, the audio system, etc.  Along with this you'd need to provide a pre-translated version of any firmware that's expected to be present on your target system so that it can be linked in to the code you're compiling.
- Second, you need to identify what parts of the ROM are actually instructions to be executed, and what parts are data (e.g. sprites, audio tracks, game level maps, etc).  The data parts need to be handled differently -- ideally, translated into a more easily accessed format (especially multi-byte numbers, either integers or floating point, which could easily be in a format that the host processor doesn't natively understand).
- Third, and possibly more interestingly, all of this may in fact be somewhat less legal than just using interpreted emulation.  Many software and hardware vendors have granted permission to allow their code (either firmware or games) to be used in emulators, as long as they remain unchanged (e.g. I know that this is the situation with the ROMs for the Sinclair ZX Spectrum, which have been released under terms like these by their current copyright holder, Amstrad PLC).  But recompiling it for a new system does change it.  Even when copyright permission hasn't been granted, there are a variety of exceptions to copyright that allow minimal copying to be performed (e.g. copying the contents of a cartridge ROM onto disk for easier access) if that's necessary to make it work -- but recompiling isn't necessary, so even where there's no explicit licence grant available it may be less legal to recompile for a new architecture than just to emulate the old one.  (I'm not a lawyer, so take this with a very large pinch of salt, but I have spent a reasonable amount of time learning about copyright law, and I'm pretty confident this position)

Comment: *"The data parts need to be handled differently"* This assumes clear separation between code and data. That's reasonable with modern software (and things like the No Execute or NX flag on memory regions make the CPU enforce it), but I imagine the separation was much less clear with the kind of code the OP likely has in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite a complete answer; however, many emulators of the consoles like playstation and alike do in some sense the same you are asking about.

Instead of precisely executing the code and precisely emulating the hardware, some typical code pieces (mostly connected with 3D transformations and rendering) are recognized as a whole and the end result is just inserted in the machine state or rendered using host 3D capabilities. The reason in doing so is probably lack of detailed hardware information and the speed of host CPU being not enough to emulate everything precilesy.